# Attribute Error in installing openpyxl

Tags: python, pip, openpyxl

I just started Python recently and would appreciate how to tackle this problem. How would I bypass this and successfully install the *openpyxl* module?

```
>> pip.main(['install', 'openpyxl==2.4.7'])
Collecting openpyxl==2.4.7
Downloading openpyxl-2.4.7.tar.gz (156kB)

[K    6% |##                              | 10kB 10.3MB/s eta 0:00:01
[K    13% |####                            | 20kB 1.1MB/s eta 0:00:01
[K    19% |######                          | 30kB 767kB/s eta 0:00:01
[K    26% |########                        | 40kB 580kB/s eta 0:00:01
[K    32% |##########                      | 51kB 539kB/s eta 0:00:01
[K    39% |############                    | 61kB 532kB/s eta 0:00:01
[K    45% |##############                  | 71kB 535kB/s eta 0:00:01
[K    52% |################                | 81kB 532kB/s eta 0:00:01
[K    58% |##################              | 92kB 529kB/s eta 0:00:01
[K    65% |####################            | 102kB 535kB/s eta 0:00:01
[K    71% |#######################         | 112kB 487kB/s eta 0:00:01
[K    78% |#########################       | 122kB 478kB/s eta 0:00:01
[K    85% |###########################     | 133kB 473kB/s eta 0:00:01
[K    91% |#############################   | 143kB 484kB/s eta 0:00:01
[K    98% |############################### | 153kB 483kB/s eta 0:00:01
[K    100% |################################| 163kB 402kB/s 
[31mException:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 324, in run
requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 634, in _prepare_file
abstract_dist.prep_for_dist()
   File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 129, in prep_for_dist
self.req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 439, in run_egg_info
command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 676, in call_subprocess
line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, in console_to_str
return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encoding'[0m
```

Answer (score 1):

First, try running pip from the command line; not from inside a Python prompt.

pip install openpyxl==2.4.7

Second, if you are on a Windows system, make sure you run the pip command from a cmd prompt 'Run as administrator'.